# ngTable multi-level or nested grouping

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using groupBy in ngTable, but now I need a further level of grouping in the table:

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    count: 100,
    sorting: {
        PremiumElementGroup: 'desc',
        PremiumElement: 'desc',
        LegalEntity: 'asc',
        SettlementCurrency: 'asc'
    }
}, {
    counts: [],
    groupBy: 'PremiumElementGroup' <--- only allows one level of grouping...
    , getData: function ($defer, params) {
        var orderedData = $filter('orderBy')($scope.section.PremiumCessionOverrides, params.orderBy());
        $defer.resolve(orderedData);
    }
});
```

Is there something I can do to achieve what I want? Or another grid tool I could use?

Comment: maybe using callback in `groupBy` property?

Comment: @KostiaMololkin I had a look at the callback example, it seems to be setting groupby to the return value of some function. How would this help me acheive multi-level grouping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, there doesn't seem to be the possibility for group nesting up to multiple levels using `ngTable`.

However, you can use [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_expandable_grid) which, according to their documentation allows nesting up to multiple levels.

At one example, their documentation says:

`SubGrid nesting can be done upto multiple levels.`.

Side-note: You are asking for multi-level grouping or nested grouping where the title of the question is a bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks for that - you are correct, strictly I am asking about multi-level/nested grouping. I have changed title to reflect.

Comment: @TomRedfern have you successfully implemented Expandable UI Grid with more then 2 or 3 levels. If yes please share plunker or fiddle or detailed explanation would be really helpful!

Comment: @ShaMoh - sorry to tell you I was not successful and had to create my own solution for this in the end, just using multiple level nesting of ng-repeat.

Comment: @TomRedfern it would be really helpful if you share the solutions. I tried in ng repeat but i cant able access the scope in that template file

Comment: @ShaMoh - apologies it was in my last job so I can no longer access that source code...